# Impala External Table Location/URI

Tags: sql, hadoop, cloudera, impala

I am troubleshooting an application issue on an External (unmanaged) Table that was created using the CREATE TABLE X LIKE PARQUET syntax via Cloudera Impala. I am trying to determine the Location of the files comprising the partitions of the External table but having difficulty determining how to do this, or finding documentation describing this.

If I do a:

```
   show create table T1;
```

I see the hive-managed location such as:

```
    LOCATION 'hdfs://nameservice1/user/hive/warehouse/databaseName'
```

If I do a:

```
    describe formatted T1;
```

I see that the table is in fact external but it doesnt give any insight on the unmanaged Location.

```
    | Table Type:   | EXTERNAL_TABLE
    | Location:     | hdfs://nameservice1/user/hive/warehouse/databaseName/T1
```

Question: 
How do I determine the Location/URI/Parent Directory of the actual external files that comprise this External Table?

Comment: You should mention the location while creating the external table, please note that the location you mention should have the rwx access to impala user.

Comment: Correct.  The external table was created using an explicit external Location (the table was created by another application team - not by me) but that external location is not listed in the `show create table` command or the `describe formatted` command.

Comment: Can you paste the whole show create table result ? And please inform your application team to mention the location ‘/path’ while creating the table. I suspect that they might be using ‘create table if not exists’ that can lead you different way. Try to drop the table and recreate it with the location.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a external table with impala or hive and you want know the location  you must put the HDFS location, for example :

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE my_db.table_name 
  (column string )  LOCATION 'hdfs_path'

The probably location o theses files if dont provite this, is under user directory that execute the comand create table.

For more detail you can see this link:

https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/impala_create_table.html

I hope to help!